# python: Using Naive Bayes Classification for classifying documents

Tags: python, algorithm

The algorithm looks really straightforward, but my only reference is wikipedia, I find the various blogs to be a little confusing.

I set this up to classify documents. I didn't use NLTK's built in Naive Bayes classifier because I didn't understand how to define the features to train.

My set up is I use NLTK to tokenize documents, I use POS tagging to weed out proper nouns and adjectives, collect these in a list of words for that document, then I go back and make a "master reference vector" of these nouns and adjectives from each document (basically the union of all these bags of words) and assign a "reference vector": a positional word vector indicating 1 or 0 whether the word at that that position in the master reference vector appears in this document.

clusters are an object that (as you can guess) contain a list of docs. among other stuff.

code:

```
class NaiveBayesClassifier(object):
 def __init__(self):
  self.ready=false

 def get_training_clusters(self,clusters,keywords):
  self.num_clusters = len(clusters)
  self.class_prob = [] #p(class)
  num_docs = 0
  self.prob_var_class = [] #  = p(var | class)
  self.ref_length = len(clusters[0].docs[0].ref_vector)
  for i in range (0,self.ref_length):
   self.var_total_prob.append(0)

  for i in range(0,self.num_clusters): #over clusters
   self.class_prob.append(len(clusters[i].docs))
   num_docs = num_docs + self.class_prob[i]
   class_var_prob = [] #  = p(var | class)
   self.prob_var_class.append([])
   for z in range (0,ref_length):
    class_var_prob[i].append(0)
   for j in range(0,self.class_prob[i]): #over docs in clusters
    for k in range(0,self.ref_length): #over variables in individual docs
     class_var_prob[k] = class_var_prob[k] + clusters[i].docs[j].ref_vector[k]
   for k in range(0,self.class_prob[i]): #over docs in clusters
    var_prob = class_var_prob[i][k] / self.class_prob[i] #total for variable i / size
    self.prob_var_class.append((1-var_prob,var_prob)) # [ p(~var | class), p(var | class) ]
  for i in range(0,self.num_clusters):
   self.class_prob[i] = self.class_prob[i] / num_docs

 def classify(self,thedoc):
  high_score = -1
  winner = -1
  for i in range (0,self.num_clusters):
   product = self.class_prob[i]
   for j in range (0,self.ref_length):
    product = product * self.prob_var_class[i][j][thedoc.ref_vector[j]]
   if high_score < product:
    high_score = product
    winner = i
  return winner # winner = argmax(p(class(x)) * product(p(var(i) | class(x)))
```

Yeah thats a lot of code. I'm specifically interested in is:

1. I calculate the probability of a doc being in a specific class
2. I create a list of probabilities of a word appearing in a doc in a specific class,
3. When classifying I return the largest value of probability of a class times product of all the probabilities of a word appearing or not appearing in that class.

Comment: So... what's your question?

Comment: That last part. Does my interpretation match the algorithm